# How to do a transparent rewrite of only the root domain for any parked domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I did not find yet an example of the following scenario, which I'm trying to accomplish:

- Rewrite ANY parked domain root to a page in a subfolder.
- The target filename must be the parked domain root, with the dots removed.
- The rewrites are transparent, the root URL will stay the same.
- Exluded from this rewrite is the primary domain root.

Example:
anyparkeddomain.com will go to primarydomain.com/foo/anyparkeddomaincom

I came up with the following, but that does not work properly because I think it needs a wildcard to make any domain work for it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([^/]*)\.$ /$1$2 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} primarydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` of `anyparkeddomain.com`?

Comment: Ug that's a mess, can you give some actual examples of the two rewrites you are trying to achieve? Use example.ecom and www.example.com  or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea. After the first rule, try this:

```
# parked domains (redirect drom www to non-www, or vice-versa should already be done)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=primarydomain.com [NC]
# for root only, serve hidden directory
RewriteRule ^$ foo/%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,DPI]
# remove dots from hidden directory
RewriteRule ^(foo/[^/.]*)\.([^/]*/)$ $1$2 [N]
```

The next pass will pick up the index file from that directory, assuming that's what you need.

Comment: @user7942 you probably don't need the `L` flag, actually.